# Adding Existing Numbers to Twilio Connect SID

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

We're currently building a Twilio Connect App and testing with our Twilio Projects.

Our main SID is e.g. AC336 and when flow through Twilio Connect, we get a new SID e.g. AC294

We can successfully authenticate with this SID and contact the REST API.

The issue is, this new SID (AC294) has no numbers associated with it, hence we can't send any messages. However, with our App, we want existing Twilio customers to authorise our App and use their existing numbers. We do not wish to or need to, offer to buy them numbers as they likely already have them on their account.

When we currently call the following using the 'new' SID, we get no data:

```
$incomingPhoneNumbers = $this->twilio->incomingPhoneNumbers
                               ->read(array(), 20);
```

But if we authenticate with our parent SID e.g. AC336 then we get our phone numbers, as expected.

Is it possible, via Twilio Connect, to make the numbers available in the 'parent' SID (AC336 in our case) available to the authorised App SID (AC294 in this example)?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer for this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. At this time, I don't believe there is a way to do this. We spoke to Twilio support at the time and they said it can't be done, you need to buy a number and assign it which makes third-party development on the platform impossible really.